# Is there a way to change directory on AWS codebuild

Tags: amazon-web-services, continuous-integration, aws-codebuild

With Snap-CI going away I've been trying to get our builds working on AWS CodeBuild. I have my buildspec.yml built out, but changing directories doesn't seem to work.

```
version: 0.1

phases:
  install:
    commands:
      - apt-get update -y
      - apt-get install -y node
      - apt-get install -y npm
  build:
    commands:
      - cd MyDir  //Expect to be in MyDir now
      - echo `pwd` //Shows /tmp/blablabla/ instead of /tmp/blablabla/MyDir
      - npm install //Fails because I'm not in the right directory
      - bower install
      - npm run ci
  post_build:
    commands:
      - echo Build completed on `date`
artifacts:
  files:
    - MyDir/MyFile.war
  discard-paths: yes
```

It seems like this should be fairly simple, but so far I haven't had any luck getting this to work.

Answer (score 53):

If you change the buildspec.yml version to 0.2 then the shell keeps its settings.
In version: 0.1 you get a clean shell for each command.

Answer (score 23):

Each command in CodeBuild runs in a separate shell against the root of your source (access root of your source from CODEBUILD_SRC_DIR environment variable).

Your possible options are

- Short circuit the commands to run under the same shell: Works when you have relatively simple buildspec (like yours).

`commands:
    - cd MyDir && npm install && bower install
    - cd MyDir && npm run ci`

- Move your commands from buildspec to a script and have more control (useful for more complicated build logic).

`commands:
    - ./mybuildscipt.sh`

Let me know if any of these work for you.

-- EDIT --

CodeBuild has since launched buildspec v0.2 where this work around is no longer required.

Comment: I've just run into the same issue.. Unfortunately cd'ing on every line does not help: 

    ```[Container] 2017/07/02 12:46:55 Command did not exit successfully cd dealer-ai && npm install exit status 1```

    ```[Container] 2017/07/02 12:46:55 Phase complete: INSTALL Success: false```

  ```[Container] 2017/07/02 12:46:55 Phase context status code: COMMAND_EXECUTION_ERROR Message: Error while executing command: cd dealer-ai && npm install. Reason: exit status 1```

Comment: CodeBuild has since launched buildspec v0.2 where this work around is no longer required. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/build-spec-ref.html#build-spec-ref-versions